# How to find the exception from the following catLog?

Tags: java, android, firebase, exception

I'm trying to find errors that the application has, but I can not identify them. Could anyone help me to identify the origin of the error through the logcat received from android vitals?

Should I analyze / post mapping?

Below is the logcat received and the code.

logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Service.GeofenceNotification.access$002 (GeofenceNotification.java)
  or                     .access$100 (GeofenceNotification.java)
  or                     .access$200 (GeofenceNotification.java)
  or                     .access$300 (GeofenceNotification.java)
  or                     .access$402 (GeofenceNotification.java)
  or                     .access$502 (GeofenceNotification.java)
  at com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Service.GeofenceNotification$1.onCancelled (GeofenceNotification.java)
  or                     .onDataChange (GeofenceNotification.java)
  at com.google.firebase.database.zzp.onCancelled (zzp.java)
  or                     .onDataChange (zzp.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzfc.zza (zzfc.java)
  or                     .zzbe (zzfc.java)
  or                     .zzc (zzfc.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr (zzgx.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run (zzhd.java)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7325)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1230)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Here my GeofenceNotification code :

```
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.MutableData;
import com.google.firebase.database.Transaction;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Auxiliares.Utils;
import com.xxxxx.xxxxx.R;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Locale;

import static com.xxxxx.xxxxx.MainActivity.remote_geofence_temp_abast;

public class GeofenceNotification {
    private static final String TAG = "GeofenceNotification";
    private static final Integer NOTIFICATION_ID = 38;
    protected Context context;
    private static NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    GeofenceNotification(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }

    void displayNotification(final String postoID, final long dataNotif) {
        DatabaseReference mPostosDBRef = Utils.getDatabase().getReference().child("postos");
        mPostosDBRef.child(postoID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dtSnap) {
                String mNome = "Nome do posto";
                if (dtSnap.exists())    { mNome = dtSnap.child("nome").getValue(String.class); }

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                boolean cfgNotif = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CfgNotif", true);
                if (cfgNotif) {
                    startNotification(context, postoID, mNome, dataNotif);
                } else {
                    gravaAbastecimento(context, postoID, dataNotif);
                }
            }
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println("****** The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
            }
        });
    }

    private void startNotification(final Context context, final String postoID, final String mNome, final long dataNotif){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        final String userID = sharedPreferences.getString("CfgUserID", "");
        final String dateQuery = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US).format(dataNotif-remote_geofence_temp_abast);

        DatabaseReference statsRef = Utils.getDatabase().getReference().child("stats").child("users").child(userID).child(postoID);
        statsRef.orderByKey().startAt(dateQuery).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dtSnap) {

                // Verifica se não existe outro abastecimento neste posto desde o tempo minimo
                if ( dtSnap.hasChildren() ) {
                    Log.w(TAG,"Tentativa de registrar abastecimento dentro do tempo mínimo : "+ remote_geofence_temp_abast/60/1000 +" minutos.");
                    Log.w(TAG,"Já existe um abastecimento realizado após "+dateQuery);
                    return;
                }

                //this is the intent that is supposed to be called when the button is clicked
                Intent intentSim = new Intent(context, notificationBtnSim.class);
                intentSim.putExtra("postoID", postoID);
                intentSim.putExtra("dataNotif", dataNotif);

                Intent intentNao = new Intent(context, notificationBtnNao.class);

                PendingIntent pendingIntentSim = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentSim, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                PendingIntent pendingIntentNao = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentNao, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                RemoteViews notificationView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_abast);

                Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
                        .setContentText(null)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gnvbr)
                        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        .setContent(notificationView)
                        .build();

                notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
                notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
                notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
                notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.US);
                String dateString=sdf.format(dataNotif);
                String notification_date = "Abastecimento em "+dateString+" hs";

                notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_sim, pendingIntentSim);
                notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_nao, pendingIntentNao);
                notificationView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_date, notification_date);
                notificationView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_posto, mNome);
                mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

                //Schedule Alarm
                Long time = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+(3540000); // tempo maximo para responder à notificação de abastecimento (59 min)
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                if (alarmManager != null) {
                    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntentSim);
                }
            }
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println("****** The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
            }
        });
    }

    public static class notificationBtnSim extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String postoID = intent.getStringExtra("postoID");
            long dataNotif = intent.getLongExtra("dataNotif", System.currentTimeMillis());

            PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            if (alarmManager != null) {
                alarmManager.cancel(sender);
            }

            mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            if (mNotificationManager != null) {
                mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
            }
            gravaAbastecimento(context, postoID, dataNotif);
        }
    }

    public static class notificationBtnNao extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            if (alarmManager != null) {
                alarmManager.cancel(sender);
            }

            mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            if (mNotificationManager != null) {
                mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void gravaAbastecimento(final Context context, final String postoID, final long dataNotif) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        final String userName = sharedPreferences.getString("CfgUserName", "");
        final String userID = sharedPreferences.getString("CfgUserID", "");

        final String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US).format(dataNotif);
        final String ano = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy", Locale.US).format(dataNotif);
        final String mes = new SimpleDateFormat("MM", Locale.US).format(dataNotif);
        final String dia = new SimpleDateFormat("dd", Locale.US).format(dataNotif);
        final String hora = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.US).format(dataNotif);

        // Grava coordenadas e horário do ultimo abastecimento e limpa flag CfgSaiuDoPosto
        Double cfgLastKnowLatitude = Double.longBitsToDouble(sharedPreferences.getLong("CfgLastKnowLatitude", 0L));
        Double cfgLastKnowLongitude = Double.longBitsToDouble(sharedPreferences.getLong("CfgLastKnowLongitude", 0L));
        editor.putLong("CfgLatLastAbast", Double.doubleToLongBits(cfgLastKnowLatitude));
        editor.putLong("CfgLngLastAbast", Double.doubleToLongBits(cfgLastKnowLongitude));
        editor.putLong("CfgLastAbast", new Date(dataNotif).getTime()).apply();
        editor.putBoolean("CfgSaiuDoPosto", false).apply();

        // grava log de registro de abastecimento
        DatabaseReference mLogDBRef = Utils.getDatabase().getReference().child("log");
        mLogDBRef.child("abastecimentos").child(ano).child(mes).child(dia).child(hora+ " "+postoID).setValue(userID+" "+userName);
        Log.w(TAG,"============================================================");
        Log.w(TAG,"Novo abastecimento registrado no posto: "+postoID+" em "+date+" hs");
        Log.w(TAG,"============================================================");

        DatabaseReference mStatDBRef = Utils.getDatabase().getReference().child("stats");
        mStatDBRef.child("postos").child(postoID).runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
            @Override
            public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                int qtde;
                if (mutableData.hasChild(userID)) {
                    qtde = Integer.parseInt(mutableData.child(userID).getValue(String.class));
                } else { qtde = 0; }
                qtde++;
                mutableData.child(userID).setValue(qtde);
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot errSnapshot) {
                Log.d(TAG, "postoTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
            }
        });

        mStatDBRef.child("users").child(userID).runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
            @Override
            public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                int qtde;
                if (mutableData.child(postoID).hasChild(date)) {
                    qtde = Integer.parseInt(mutableData.child(postoID).child(date).getValue(String.class));
                } else { qtde = 0; }
                qtde++;
                mutableData.child(postoID).child(date).setValue(qtde);
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot errSnapshot) {
                Log.d(TAG, "usersTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here part of my MappingFile:

```
com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Service.GeofenceNotification -> com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Service.GeofenceNotification:
    java.lang.Integer NOTIFICATION_ID -> a
    android.content.Context context -> b
    android.app.NotificationManager mNotificationManager -> c
    int qtde -> d
    android.content.SharedPreferences sharedPreferences -> e
    void <init>(android.content.Context) -> <init>
    android.content.SharedPreferences access$000(com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Service.GeofenceNotification) -> a
    void access$100(com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Service.GeofenceNotification,android.content.Context,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,long) -> a
    void access$200(android.content.Context,java.lang.String,long) -> a
    android.app.NotificationManager access$300() -> a
    android.app.NotificationManager access$302(android.app.NotificationManager) -> a
    int access$402(int) -> a
    int access$408() -> b
    int access$400() -> c
    void <clinit>() -> <clinit>
com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Service.GeofenceNotification$1 -> com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Service.GeofenceNotification$1:
    java.lang.String val$postoID -> a
    long val$dataNotif -> b
    com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Service.GeofenceNotification this$0 -> c
    void <init>(com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Service.GeofenceNotification,java.lang.String,long) -> <init>
    void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot) -> a
    void onCancelled(com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError) -> a
com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Service.GeofenceNotification$2 -> com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Service.GeofenceNotification$2:
    java.lang.String val$dateQuery -> a
    android.content.Context val$context -> b
    java.lang.String val$postoID -> c
    long val$dataNotif -> d
    java.lang.String val$mNome -> e
    com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Service.GeofenceNotification this$0 -> f
    void <init>(com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Service.GeofenceNotification,java.lang.String,android.content.Context,java.lang.String,long,java.lang.String) -> <init>
    void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot) -> a
    void onCancelled(com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError) -> a
com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Service.GeofenceNotification$3 -> com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Service.GeofenceNotification$3:
    java.lang.String val$userID -> a
    void <init>(java.lang.String) -> <init>
    com.google.firebase.database.Transaction$Result doTransaction(com.google.firebase.database.MutableData) -> a
    void onComplete$5e9da46a(com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError) -> a
com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Service.GeofenceNotification$4 -> com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Service.GeofenceNotification$4:
    java.lang.String val$postoID -> a
    java.lang.String val$date -> b
    void <init>(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) -> <init>
    com.google.firebase.database.Transaction$Result doTransaction(com.google.firebase.database.MutableData) -> a
    void onComplete$5e9da46a(com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError) -> a
com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Service.GeofenceNotification$notificationBtnNao -> com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Service.GeofenceNotification$notificationBtnNao:
    void <init>() -> <init>
    void onReceive(android.content.Context,android.content.Intent) -> onReceive
com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Service.GeofenceNotification$notificationBtnSim -> com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Service.GeofenceNotification$notificationBtnSim:
    void <init>() -> <init>
    void onReceive(android.content.Context,android.content.Intent) -> onReceive
com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Service.GeofenceService -> com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Service.GeofenceService:
    android.content.SharedPreferences sharedPreferences -> d
    android.app.PendingIntent mGeofencePendingIntent -> e
    java.util.ArrayList mGeofenceList -> a
    java.lang.Double cfgLastKnowLatitude -> f
    java.lang.Double cfgLastKnowLongitude -> g
    long cfgSaiu -> h
    float maiorDist -> i
    com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient -> j
    com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingClient mGeofencingClient -> k
    java.util.Timer timer -> l
    android.location.Location mLastLocation -> b
    boolean $assertionsDisabled -> c
    void <init>() -> <init>
    android.os.IBinder onBind(android.content.Intent) -> onBind
    void onCreate() -> onCreate
    int onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,int,int) -> onStartCommand
    void onDestroy() -> onDestroy
    android.app.PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() -> b
    void populateGeofenceList() -> c
    void getLastLocation() -> a
    void getRemoteVariables() -> d
    java.lang.Double access$002(com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Service.GeofenceService,java.lang.Double) -> a
    java.lang.Double access$102(com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Service.GeofenceService,java.lang.Double) -> b
    java.lang.Double access$000(com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Service.GeofenceService) -> a
    android.content.SharedPreferences access$200(com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Service.GeofenceService) -> b
    java.lang.Double access$100(com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Service.GeofenceService) -> c
    long access$302(com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Service.GeofenceService,long) -> a
    long access$308(com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Service.GeofenceService) -> d
    long access$300(com.xxxxx.xxxxx.Service.GeofenceService) -> e
    void <clinit>() -> <clinit>
```

I need a lot of help finding this error, and I do not know where the cause of this exception is (access).

Comment: In onCancelled() ? `System.out.println("****** The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());` Check if databaseError==null and if so do not print.

Comment: If not then remove all code from onDataChange() to test if that causes it.

Comment: I think the problem was really this (getCode). I've posted a new version and am waiting to complete the update. As soon as I confirm, I will mark your answer as correct. Thank you!

Comment: greenapps, you are right. the getCode was the cause of this exception. please answer and i´ll set up as right answer for this question. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

In onCancelled() ?

```
System.out.println("****** The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
```

Check if databaseError==null and if so do not print.